# How to parse a JSON.stringify in a Firebase set?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, local-storage

I have the step#1 that attends others goals. However, its results doesn't work in step#2 when the variable is record in a specific node.

The code does this:

**Step #1** function record(){}

```
localStorage.setItem(prod_id, JSON.stringify(object));
```

**Step #2** function save(){}

```
var dbHistory = localStorage.getItem(prod_id, JSON.stringify(object));
const App = firebase.database();
App.ref('/wc2017/' + prod_id + '/stats').set({dbHistory});
```

**Console**
  Everything is okay When I check through Console.log(dbHistory)

**Result**

```
stats = "{\"version\":\"1.2.3\",\"first_in\":0,\"batch\":{\"date\":1505374041027},\"route\":{},\"kanban\":[],\"sigma\":\"0-0\"}"
```

---

**Expected Result**

The json file from https://xxx.firebaseio.com/wc2017/prod_id/stats like this. How to do this?

```
{
  "version": "1.2.3",
  "first_in": 0,
  "batch": {
    "date": 1505368006892
  },
  "route": {},
  "kanban": [],
  "sigma": "0-0"
}
```

Comment: Did you tried JSON.parse(data) ?

Comment: @ShubhamJain Yes, I did. But for some reason I get VM15657:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o [object Object]

Comment: It is working fine for me I cannot reproduce the error. I tried to parse "{\"version\":\"1.2.3\",\"first_in\":0,\"batch\":{\"date\":1505374041027},\"route\":{},\"kanban\":[],\"sigma\":\"0-0\"}" . It gives no error and sends the expected result back.

Comment: @ShubhamJain The intranet source is the problem. Sometimes It set up JSON with new node with undefined value.

Comment: It should be closed because I need to treat JSON before loading to Firebase.